# iPad Air not connecting to iTunes (12.3.2), MacBook Air Mid-2011

Tags: ipad

Just bought an iPad Air, but when I connect it to the macbook air it doesn't show up on iTunes. I did press trust this computer, but the Ipad only charges. Could be because I am running developer beta versions all the time on my Mac.

iTunes (12.3.2),
El Capitan 10.11.3 Beta (15D9c)

Comment: Did you buy it new or used?

Comment: i bought it used

Comment: the problem was the charger cable, took a new one and everything works

Answer (score 1):

Is your iPad recognized in the "Devices" section of "System Information"? Also check to see if Photos.app will recognize the iPad. It's possible that there is a problem with iTunes itself and not the iPad.

Comment: System profiler sees it. Xcode and photos doesn't. It just shows that there is IPad in my USB port from the profiler but that is it.